# Record payment method

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, payment

I am working on a marketplace application and am looking to register payment methods (currently PayPal only) for buyers. The perfect flow is like on Uber or Airbnb:
The buyer manages these payment methods, choosing one by default, and when he goes to pay, he does not have to go through the checkout of PayPal; it will be enough to press a button, and his balance will be debited.
I can’t find documentation with PayPal API for this flow, do you have any recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

To be able to bill a PayPal account at arbitrary times *without* the payer signing in (though they will always have to sign in for initial agreement/set up of storing it as a payment method), the receiving PayPal business account must have a feature called "reference transactions". The account owner can contact PayPal's general business support (not technical support) to explain the business need and inquire about being approved for enabling this feature. Once enabled for "reference transactions", PayPal can guide you on which API to implement -- be it the older billing agreements API or a newer v2 or v3 vault one.

---

But if the customer is always going to be present to click on a PayPal JS SDK button to approve every payment, then vault can be used *without* the reference transactions feature.